# Call React hook depending on Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, native

I have an ID stored in AsyncStorage and depending on this call, I want to make a server request.

So something like this is needed:

```
AsyncStorage.getID().then(id => {
   useLoadFromServer(id)
}
```

But I always struggle with getting errors about using hooks wrong. So far I tried:

```
// First Approach
const MyScreen = () => {
  const [ID, setID] = useState()

  AsyncStorage.getID()
    .then(id => setID(id))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
  
  const { data } = useLoadRoot(ID) // Not the ID from AsyncStorage is used
}
```

```
//Second Approach
const MyScreen = async () => {
  const [ID, setID] = useState()

  const IDPromise = AsyncStorage.getID()
  const { data } = useLoadRoot(await IDPromise) // Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection
```

also I tried to use `useEffect`, which leads to `React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

The useLoadRoot-hook just calls another hook `UseLoadFromEndpoint` doing the `axios.get()`

When trying to move the AsyncStorage-Request to the customHook, I get the same errors, as I call the `useLoadFromEndpoint`-hook incorrectly, but I have to / want to reuse the UseLoadFromEndpoint-Hook. How can I achive this?

Comment: What is the inplementation of `useLoadFromServer` and `useLoadRoot`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either modify the `useLoadRoot` hook or wrap that logic in a child component. Hooks don't allow conditional usage.

### Route 1: Rewrite `useLoadRoot`

```
const useLoadRoot = (id) => {
  const getRoot = async (rootId) => ...;
  const [root, setRoot] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id != undefined) { 
       await getRoot(id);
    }
  }, [id]);

  return root;
}
```

This is just one way to achieve what you want. You can pass in an enabled property that is a boolean that allows requests only if true. This is the approach that is used in react-query, for example (see: [docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-querieshttps://)).

### Route 2: Conditional child component

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [ID, setID] = useState()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getID()
      .then(id => setID(id))
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }, []);

  return ID ? <WithFetchRoot rootId={ID}/> : null; //could be a loader component instead of null
}

const WithFetchRoot = (id) => {
  const root = useLoadRoot(ID);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. Created a HOG with your solution and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The rules of hooks state that all hooks must run in the same order with each render cycle. This means we need to write conditional logic in a particular way. I would recommend this.

```
const MyScreen = () => {
  const [ID, setID] = useState()
  cosnt [data, setData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const id = await AsyncStorage.getID()
      setID(id)
      const { data } = useLoadRoot(id)
      setData(data)
    }
    getData()
  })
  
  if (data) {
    // do stuff
  }
  return null
}
```

Comment: It is not allowed to call hooks in `useEffect`, thats the point of my question.

Comment: its very common to use hooks in useEffect, your problem is not returning null because every SINGLE COMPOENENT needs to return something and undefined doesn't work. Ive got downvoted for some reason but you can read my answer and check out the react page for more information @Steffi

Comment: @MrCeRaYA is correct. I slipped that in without really thinking about it but the return statement is an essential part of a component.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have no `return`. All react components should return something so return `null` from your component and it should solve your problem. Also, to avoid unnecessary rendering, you should do it in useEffect with an empty array so it only get triggers once (after the component mounts).